# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems Duplicate local variable

Tags: java

Hello I've got this error message (caused likely by the last method "choixNumerote") :

```
 java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Duplicate local variable tabJoueur
    Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
    sc cannot be resolved
```

any help ?

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mastermind_ho {
    static String [] TAB_REF_COLORS = {"rouge","jaune","vert","bleu","orange","blanc","violet","fuchsia"};
    static int NB_COLORS = 4;
    static int compteur=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] combinaisonSecrete = generateRandomCombination();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            System.out.println(combinaisonSecrete[i]);
        }

        String [] combinaisonJoueur = choixNumerote();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            System.out.println(combinaisonJoueur[i]);
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    // Generate random combination of 4 colors 
    static String [] generateRandomCombination() {
        String [] combination = new String[NB_COLORS];
        int currentPosition = 0;
        while(currentPosition!=NB_COLORS) {
            int indexRandom = (int)(Math.random()*TAB_REF_COLORS.length);
            String color = TAB_REF_COLORS[indexRandom];
            if(!isIn(color, combination)) {
                combination[currentPosition] = color;
                currentPosition++;
            }
        }
        return combination;
    }

    static boolean isIn(String iStringToFind, String [] iTab) {
        int size = iTab.length;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            if(iStringToFind.equalsIgnoreCase(iTab[i])) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static String [] choixNumerote() {
        String [] tabJoueur = new String[NB_COLORS];
        for(int i=0;i<NB_COLORS;i++) {
            System.out.println("Choisissez une couleur :");
            String tabJoueur[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }
        compteur++;
        return tabJoueur;
        System.out.println("Il te reste : " + (12-compteur) + "tentative(s)");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] tabJoueur = new String[NB_COLORS];
for(int i=0;i<NB_COLORS;i++) {
    System.out.println("Choisissez une couleur :");
    String tabJoueur[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
```

You declared tabJoueur again with type `String`. Correct it:

```
String [] tabJoueur = new String[NB_COLORS];
for(int i=0;i<NB_COLORS;i++) {
    System.out.println("Choisissez une couleur :");
    tabJoueur[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
```

Also, you should learn to trust your compiler's error messages, since it clearly tells you what the problem is.

Comment: thank you @Steyrix but another error message has appeared after deleting "String" :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 sc cannot be resolved

 at Mastermind_ho.choixNumerote(Mastermind_ho.java:67)
 at Mastermind_ho.main(Mastermind_ho.java:34)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, remove `String` from `String tabJoueur[i]=sc.nextLine();`

[image]

Comment: I deleted the String but got another error message in the same line : 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 sc cannot be resolved

 at Mastermind_ho.choixNumerote(Mastermind_ho.java:67)
 at Mastermind_ho.main(Mastermind_ho.java:34)"

Comment: if you notice `String tabJoueur[i]=sc.nextLine();` look properly, where else is sc declared in this method? it doesn't exist. What you can do instead is pass the scanner as a parameter  `static String choixNumerote(Scanner sc) {`, then in your `main` method `String [] combinaisonJoueur = choixNumerote(sc);`

Comment: In fact, it was "only" the order in wich the last instructions has been written .... weirdo this Java, isn't it??

I've written this and it works :

compteur++;
System.out.println("Il te reste : " + (12-compteur) + " tentative(s)");
return tabJoueur;

instead of :
compteur++;
return tabJoueur;
System.out.println("Il te reste : " + (12-compteur) + "tentative(s)");

Thank you for your answers

Comment: oooh yeah i did not see that, you should never do any operations after a return statement, but your compiler should tell you that? use `intellij`. No worries mate and I'm not a fan of java tbh :D

Comment: But I declared it in the top of the code. It's not sufficient?

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mastermind_ho {
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static String [] TAB_REF_COLORS = {"rouge","jaune","vert","bleu","orange","blanc","violet","fuchsia"};
static int NB_COLORS = 4;
static int compteur=0;

Comment: Thak you Bargros .. you're great